# Input field to only accept a specific number

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, input

I have created a form and now I want to add an input field inside it which would only accept a specific number i.e. the digit '4'. This is more like a spam check where the user is asked that 'What is the answer of 1+3?' and then he/she would've to enter the digit '4', in the input field, in order for the form to get processed. This could also work in a manner that if any other number is entered inside the input field and the form is submitted, a pop up window is fired explaining the error.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bxc5K/7/) which only accepts the digit 4 but sadly it is allow accepting 'full stops'.

HTML:

```
<input id="humancheck" type="text" maxlength="1" name="humancheck" required />
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery('#humancheck').keyup(function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^4-4\.]/g,'');
});
```

Comment: A spam check in javascript is kind of pointless.  Bots will not bother with your `keyup` code.

Comment: If you don't want to allow a full stop, why do you have one in the regex?

Comment: Why don't you simply just check it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Bxc5K/10/

Comment: A spambot is functionally equivalent to a user with JavaScript disabled, so any spam check that you create in JavaScript won't actually prevent spam. You need to do server-side validation for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex should only be replacing `[^4]` (any character which is not 4). I'm not sure why you have also included `-4` (range) and `\.` ('.' character).

Just to note, securing on keyup doesn't help much. Anyone can fire up webkit inspector and place a 3 in there manually. If this is just a fun experiment, though, that's cool too :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a bit moldy, so I thought I might bring it a bit more current.

First, you should not use the 'keyup' for the event trigger, as it is to processor intensive. Imagine if you were wanting to match a number with more than one digit, and you can see how the 'keyup' becomes problematic.

Using the 'blur' event is a better trigger, as it checks the number value **after the user has finished** entering a number into the form field.

If I am understanding the OP, then why use a regex at all for a simple
match? Instead, this is one way I would write your function (for jQuery 1.11.0+). It also makes an additional check to assure the entry is indeed a number as well.

```
$('#humancheck').blur( function(){ 
  if (isNaN(this.value)) alert('Not a Number');
  if (this.value != 4) alert('Incorrect Number');
});
```